# Existence of class modules for finite groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, group-cohomology

I'm reading *Cohomology of Number Fields* by Neukirch et al. Let $G$ be a finite group. A $G$-module C is a **class module** if, for all subgroups $H \subset G$:

1) $H^1(H,C)=0$

2) $H^2(H,C)$ is cyclic of order $\#H$

Remark: If $G$ is cyclic then $\mathbb{Z}$ is a class module.

***Question:*** Does every finite group admit a class module? If yes: is there a standard construction of such a C given G?